# Installed VS2012 - now cannot connect to SQL server with SSMS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ssms

Since installing VS 2012 and un-installing VS 2010, I am now unable to connect to our SQL Server using Management Studio 2012 (which was already installed)

All I get is

> *A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (privider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - the wait operation timed out) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)
>
>   the wait operation timed out*

I have 'repaired' my SQL Server 2012 tools instance, but still no worky. I can connect to local instances - unfortunately this is of no use at all

Any ideas on this one? I'm thinking I will have to uninstall the lot and start again, which surprise surprise I'd rather not have to do

**EDIT: ok so having googled a bit more, I uninstalled .net 4.5 (and installed .net 4.0) and magically SMSS connected again, but of course VS2012 then stopped working. so I installed VS2012 again, and low and behold SMSS refuses to connect again. what frickin gives?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should installing SQL Server 2012 first before you install VS 2012.

Uninstalling VS 2010 will also break VS 2010 IDE that is included with SQL Server 2010.

Comment: sql 2012 was already installed, i dont have licenses for both vs2010 and 2012, so uninstalled 2010 and put on 2012, then sql management studio stops connecting to anything other than local instances

Comment: @nat you missed my point man. You should never uninstall vs 2010, otherwise you will have to reinstall sql server 2012 again.

Comment: you should reinstall sql server 2012 but then repair vs 2012 installation.

Comment: turns out i can connect if i use named pipes instead of TCP/IP, of course this means I cant connect to prod, but can to dev and test ffs

Comment: ...and re-installing sql 2012 tools is not enough then I guess

Comment: @nat of course is not enough.. I mean repair sql server 2012, not reinstall it.

Comment: the first thing I did was reinstall the sql tools, are you saying that although the problem is with the tools, I need to repair my whole local sql server instance?

Comment: Yes, it is. And please enable TCP/IP, not just named pipes.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I had a content filter/proxy called Covenant Eyes that was the likely cause.

I tried repairing the install of SQL server 2012 (just for management studio!) and it crashed the install and still did not fix the problem. As soon as I generated an uninstall code and uninstalled the filter, I could connect; I did not even have to reboot.

Check for proxies and content filters on the machine and disable them!

Answer (score -1):

Believe it or not!  Error is caused by Apple Itunes messing with the winsock on the machine.  I often need to reset the winsock because of crappy Itunes.  You dont need to uninstall .net or studio etc.

Open command prompt under admin priv
Type 
netsh winsock reset
reboot

Magic you can connect.

Your welcome.

Comment: How do you know the user has Itunes?

Comment: unsurprisingly I wouldnt install itunes if they paid me.. pah!